# Blender renders my material incorrectly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image]

All the black object have the same material but only the outside floor renders it correctly, what can I do to change this?

Comment: Under the "Color" settings within the "Surface" panel, what happens if you change "Flat" to "Box"? Does your mesh have a UV map? Are you able to post a .blend file?

Comment: In your screenshot it is not really rendered (in Cycles), it is in material view mode.  Material view mode basically tries to convert the material to a texture, which does not work very well in Cycles.  Try shifting to *Rendered View* mode.  It also looks like you may not have a UV map on the black object.